# How to define quotation mark as constant in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Simply I'm trying to define the quotation mark (") as a constant in Visual Basic. However, VB automatically inserts another ", hence I can't make the char equals to an ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the ASCII character (34) in Visual Basic like

```
TextBox1.Text = "She said, " & Chr(34) & "You deserve a treat!" & Chr(34)
```

You can also define a constant for the character, and use it where needed.

```
Const quote As String = """"
TextBox1.Text = "She said, " & quote & "You deserve a treat!" & quote
```

Taken from [How to: Put Quotation Marks in a String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Two quote marks make an escaped quote mark.

```
variable = """"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a normal " because the program is used to create Wiki code, thus the type of the mark can't be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? That is a normal ". Just use two of them in a row in any VB string, like `"this is ""quoted"" text"`.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood what you're trying to tell. you answer is correct but I can't upvote at my current rep.